# 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04, vim not able to add numbers using C-a

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, vim

In vim, on a 32-bit system, when I try to add by hitting Control-A to any number more than 10-digits, vim does not add up properly.

On a 64-bit system with the same settings (same vim version, etc.) the addition can take place up to 20 digits, but breaks beyond that.

Is this because of 32-bit, 64-bit operating system? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this depends on the 32-bit operating system.

:help ^a

> The CTRL-A and CTRL-X commands work for (signed) decimal
>   numbers, unsigned octal and hexadecimal numbers and
>   alphabetic characters.

These are the exact limits:

```
$ echo 2^32 | bc
4294967296
$ echo 2^64 | bc
18446744073709551616
```